# Open excel from word and select specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Im using following code to select a particular range in a selected sheet in excel

```
Sub openWordvanuitWord()

Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
Dim Excel As Excel.Workbook
Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet

Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excelApp.Visible = True

Set Excel = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and   Settings\aa471714\Desktop\Book1.xls")
Set sht = Excel.Worksheets(1)


With sht

.Range("b3:h5").Select


End With

End Sub
```

Problem is that it want it to select sheet 2. Only when I change

```
Set sht = Excel.Worksheets(1)
```

to

```
Set sht = Excel.Worksheets(2)
```

I get an error

Anybody suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set the selection on the *active* worksheet.
So you have to activate it first:

```
Set sht = Excel.Worksheets(2)
sht.activate
With sht
    .Range("b3:h5").Select
End With
```

Btw: In most cases you don't have to work with the selection (you can read and write values without using that, for example) but that's another topic...

Comment: + 1 on the last sentence. For OP: Please avoid the use of `.Select/.Activate` [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)